# Text file specification field separator matches decimal separator

Tags: .net, csv, oledb

в приложении при импорте csv возникает ошибка.
Error: "Text file specification field separator matches decimal separator or text delimiter" When using the Microsoft OLE DB data provider to import CSV files.
Приложение работет корректно на английской винде, на русской после смены локали и настроек форматинга ошибка проявляется все равно

Строка подключения: Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Temp\Import\X1\1611011205-da5b1c75be444fa2b61‌​5e36d4ee0b009\SEF;Ex‌​tended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";

пример csv:
"cvncvncvn"
"cvbmcvmm"
"cm"

Comment: Покажите строку подключения. Попробуйте явно задать delimiter/separator и кодировку в строке подключения. Укажите версию офиса. Попробуйте указать предопределённые столбцы.

Comment: Строка подключения:  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Temp\Import\X1\1611011205-da5b1c75be444fa2b615e36d4ee0b009\SEF;Extended Properties="text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";

Comment: пример csv  "cvncvncvn"
"cvbmcvmm"
"cm"

Comment: А вы не пробовали положить schema.ini?

Comment: проблема в том, что импортируются архивы с csv файлами,  и бага возникает на этапе создания своего schema.ini, аттачить в архив schema.ini не совсем то что нужно.

Comment: У вас загаловки на русском и разделитель пробел?

Comment: заголовок - "cvncvncvn" , разделитель пробел. Импорт будет успешен, если разделитель указывать как табуляция